# Create a mapping table with hibernate and retrieve values by columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

i am working on Spring Data JPA with Hibernate. I want to create a mapping table using hibernate automatically and want to retrieve the values based on the id's of each individual tables.

CustomerEntity.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "customers")
@Entity
public class CustomerEntity  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "customerId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID customerId;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customerEntities")
    private List<ItemEntity> itemEntities;



   //More customer fields

}
```

ItemEntity.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "items")
@Entity
public class ItemEntity  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "itemId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID itemId;





   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId", nullable = false)
    private List<CustomerEntity> customerEntities;

   //More item fields

}
```

Now i want to create a mapping table with manyToMany for these two based on the id's

something like below:

MappingTable:

```
id // Primary Key

customerId // primary key from customer table

itemId // primary key from item table
```

and i want to use customerId or itemId (depends on which i have available) to find the records within the mapping table.

Can any one please provide any suggestions would be helpful here. TIA.

Comment: I don't think you need a tertiary table with its own primary key.  Instead you could just build a bidirectional `@ManyToMany` mapping between `Customer` and `Item` in the two entity classes you have and the underlying table would treat the `customerId`+`itemId` as the primary key.  Is there a reason you need such a tertiary table design as you have outlined?

Comment: @Naros Thanks for the suggestion, but i am from tradtional sql world where we define DDL and DML for creating and maintaing relationships. May be i am still thinking in that perspective. I am very new to hibernate and still learning things. If you can please provide an example and also how to retrive the values from the new table that hibernate will create that will be really helpful. To answer your questions, no there is no special reason . We just went with that as we dont know that hibernate can take care of the mappings.

Comment: Please read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many.  It covers all your questions in decent detail, including examples.  For what its worth, if you need a _link entity_ to cover the specific case you described above, the docs cover that scenario as well.

Comment: @Naros i have updated the code with above annotations. I can see the mapping table is being created but i dont the entries with in the Items table and the mapping table. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you adding the associations correctly, e.g. adding `ItemEntity` to the customer object and `CustomerEntity` to the associated `ItemEntity` objects?  Hibernate doesn't just magically _assign_ the association, you have to do that too.  See the part about helper methods to maintain the relationships in the documentation.

Comment: @Naros Yes. Now i changed to the above updated code . I can see that data is in customers tables and items table seperately but in the customers_items mapping tables entry is not made. Not really sure whats happening here :(.. Any idea where the mapping is gone wrong and i am trying to use hibernate with springboot

Comment: Can we please  [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199541/discussion-between-ging-and-naros). @Naros